# Spring @ExceptionHandler and HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and this method in it:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ResponseBody
public ExceptionInfo resourceNotFoundHandler(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    List<ErrorContent> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    errors.add(new ErrorContent(ExceptionsCodes.NOT_FOUND_CODE, null,
            "test"));
    return fillExceptionInfo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, errors, ex);
}
```

Here is `fillExceptionInfo`:

```
public ExceptionInfo fillExceptionInfo(HttpStatus status, List<ErrorContent> errors, 
        Exception ex) {
    String msg = ex.getMessage();

    return new ExceptionInfo(status.toString(), errors, (msg != null && !msg.equals(""))
            ? ex.getMessage()
            : ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
}
```

When a web-client send a request for some json data, which cannot be found, this method works ok. But when server receives a request to image, instead of my exception a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` is thrown. I understand that it happens because of wrong content type, but how can I fix this problem?

**Update**

My goal is to throw `ResourceNotFoundException` in both cases for json data and for file.

Exception that I get (so it is thrown from `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor`):

```
ERROR o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - doResolveHandlerMethodException - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public com.lia.utils.GlobalExceptionHandler$ExceptionInfo com.lia.utils.GlobalExceptionHandler.resourceNotFoundHandler(com.lia.app.controllers.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException) 
    org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:198) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1167) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1004) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:717) [jetty-servlet-9.1.1.v20140108.jar:9.1.1.v20140108]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644) [jetty-servlet-9.1.1.v20140108.jar:9.1.1.v20140108]
....
```

Comment: What is your goal? To handle `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`s or to have your method throw a `ResourceNotFoundException` in both cases? Also, please post the method that throws the exception.

Comment: @hzpz I've updated my question accordingly to your comment, please look through my edits

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem lies in the incompatibility of the requested content type and the object being returned. See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372113/466738) on how to configure the `ContentNegotiationConfigurer` so that Spring determines the requested content type according to your needs (looking at the path extension, URL parameter or `Accept` header).

Depending on how the requested content type is determined, you have following options when an image is requested by the client:

- if the requested content type is determined by the `Accept` header, and if the client can/wants to handle a JSON response instead of the image data, then the client should send the request with `Accept: image/*, application/json`. That way Spring knows that it can safely return either the image byte data or the error JSON message.
- in any other case your best solution is to just return a HTTP error code, without any error message. You can do that in a couple of ways in your controller:

Set the error code on the response directly

```
public byte[] getImage(HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
        // return your image
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Use `ResponseEntity`

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getImage(HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
        byte[] img = // your image
        return ReponseEntity.ok(img);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Use a separate `@ExceptionHandler` method **in that controller**, which will override the default Spring exception handling. That assumes you have either a dedicated exception type for image requests or a separate controller just for serving the images. Otherwise, the exception handler will handle exceptions from other endpoints in that controller, too.

Answer (score 6):

What does your `ExceptionInfo` class look like? I run into quite similar issue after defining a few exception handlers in `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class. When exception happened it was caught, although the response was not return and `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation` was thrown.

I figured out that the problem was caused by the fact, that I missed to add getter methods to my `ErrorResponse` class. After adding getter methods (this class was immutable, so there were no setter methods) everything worked like a charm.

Comment: The error is a little bit tricky, but this solved it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to ignore the explicit instruction of your client, as expressed in the `Accept` header, you can tinker with the content negotiation strategy like so:

```java
/**
 * Content negotiation strategy that adds the {@code application/json} media type if not present in the "Accept"
 * header of the request.
 * <p>
 * Without this media type, Spring refuses to return errors as {@code application/json}, and thus not return them at
 * all, which leads to a HTTP status code 406, Not Acceptable
 */
class EnsureApplicationJsonNegotiationStrategy extends HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy {
    @Override
    public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes(NativeWebRequest request) throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>(super.resolveMediaTypes(request));
        if (notIncludesApplicationJson(mediaTypes)) {
            mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
        return mediaTypes;
    }

    private boolean notIncludesApplicationJson(List<MediaType> mediaTypes) {
        return mediaTypes.stream()
                .noneMatch(mediaType -> mediaType.includes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

Use this in a `@Configuration` class like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class ContentNegotiationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.strategies(List.of(
                new EnsureApplicationJsonNegotiationStrategy()
        ));
    }
}
```

Unit tests (using JUnit 5, Mockito):

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EnsureApplicationJsonNegotiationStrategyTest {
    @Mock
    private NativeWebRequest request;

    @InjectMocks
    private EnsureApplicationJsonNegotiationStrategy subject;

    @Test
    public void testAddsApplicationJsonToAll() throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        when(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)).thenReturn(new String[]{"*/*"});

        assertThat(subject.resolveMediaTypes(request), contains(
                MediaType.ALL // this includes application/json, so... fine
        ));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddsApplicationJsonToEmpty() throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        when(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)).thenReturn(new String[0]);

        assertThat(subject.resolveMediaTypes(request), contains(
                MediaType.ALL // that's what the default does, which includes application/json, so... fine
        ));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddsApplicationJsonToExisting() throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        when(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)).thenReturn(new String[]{"application/something"});

        assertThat(subject.resolveMediaTypes(request), containsInAnyOrder(
                MediaType.valueOf("application/something"),
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        ));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddsApplicationJsonToNull() throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        when(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)).thenReturn(null);

        assertThat(subject.resolveMediaTypes(request), contains(
                MediaType.ALL // that's what the default does, which includes application/json, so... fine
        ));
    }

    @Test
    public void testRetainsApplicationJson() throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        when(request.getHeaderValues(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)).thenReturn(new String[]{"application/json"});

        assertThat(subject.resolveMediaTypes(request), contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Based on previous answers from Sander Verhagen and Adam Michalik)

I finally wrote a way to avoid twice exceptions result: a content negociation failure ('Accept' not valid) while already executing an exception handler method.

I tell to spring to resolve as APPLICATION_JSON in the case the request media type is not well formatted.
So this way there is no more a "on-fly" content negotiation error when producing exception handler response.

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.strategies(singletonList(
                new EnsureValidMediaTypesNegotiationStrategy()
        ));
    }
}

@Slf4j
class EnsureValidMediaTypesNegotiationStrategy extends HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy {
    @Override
    public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes(NativeWebRequest request) throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        try {
            return super.resolveMediaTypes(request);
        } catch (Exception negotiationException) {
            // this fix is used to avoid twice exceptions due to media negotiation
            log.info("Client Accept header is not recognized (json response enforced):{}", negotiationException.getMessage());
            return singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }

    }
}
```

Note you could add some test to your controller using this value as "Accept" header :

```
../../../../../../../../../../../../../e*c/h*s*s{{
```